# Cluedo with bonus cards. Does move anywhere card let you interact with the place you entered?

Tags: cluedo

I own a Cluedo version that has some bonus cards, which are collected by ending your turn in a red question mark on the board. These bonus cards are: Bonus question, Make someone reveal a card, move anywhere, add six to your dice roll, take a sneaky peek, and take an extra turn.

My confusion is mainly about two cards: Add six to your dice roll, and move anywhere. The description of the other cards is pretty obvious; but what about the 'move anywhere card'? Am I allowed to move anywhere **and** interact with the place I have moved to? For example:

It is my turn and I drew a 'move anywhere card', can I move to another question mark and take another bonus card? Can I move to any room **and** make an accusation? Or am I only allowed to move (which could be very pointless, given that somebody else could move my character throughout the next round).

How about the 'add six to your dice roll'?

Both possibilities seem odd (if you are allowed to interact with the place you move to, then these cards are almost the same as 'take an extra turn'), but which one is correct?

Answer (score 1):

If you give us the version name we can give you a better answer but based on what you wrote :

- Since you draw cards at the end of your turn you *should* not be able to use them instantly
- I guess that the move anywhere is instead of moving or before moving, if that's the case you *should* be able to interact with the room...
- Otherwise you shouldn't be able to interact
- You can add six to a dice only after rolling them, since you drew cards after moving, you *shouldn't* be able to use it instantly in order to move again

That's all we can conclude without the edition's name.